# hive script file not found exception

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive

I am running below command file is in my local directory but I am getting below error while running the file.

```
[hdfs@ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx scripts]$ ls -lrt
total 28
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    17 Apr  1 15:53 hive.hive  
-rwxrwxrwx  1 hdfs hadoop  88 May  7 11:53 shell_fun  
-rwxrwxrwx  1 hdfs hadoop 262 May  7 12:23 first_hive  
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    88 May  7 16:59 311_cust_shell  
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   822 May  8 20:29 script_1  
-rw-r--r--  1 hdfs hadoop  31 May  8 20:30 script_1.log  
**-rwxrwxrwx  1 hdfs hdfs    64 May  8 22:07 **hql2.sql*** 

[hdfs@ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx scripts]$ hive -f hql2.sql
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.3.4.0-3485/0/hive-log4j.properties Could not open input file for reading.  
(File file:/home/ec2-user/scripts/hive/scripts/hql2.sql does not exist)
[hdfs@ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx scripts]$
```

Comment: You should check what you've posted. The emphasis did not work yet, which made it hard to see what had happened.

Comment: what is the current directory path?

Comment: Sorry if it is not understandable,  I am calling hql2.sql using hive -e command, but despite it being in the same directory I am getting error saying file not found.

Comment: @AmitSharma - seems your hive script file is recognized as `file:/home/ec2-user/scripts/hive/scripts/hql2.sql` not as `/home/ec2-user/scripts/hive/scripts/hql2.sql`

Comment: What does this mean , how can I make it look for the file path i have.

Comment: are u able to solve this problem? I'm also getting the same error message.